# What is the $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$-topology?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, lp-spaces

In [chapter 4, paragraph 6](https://books.google.com/books?id=qS3gZasNfdQC&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=%22Throughout%20this%20section%20we%20will%20use%20the%20setting%20and%20notation%20of%22&source=bl&ots=Q8S-DJXVf3&sig=ACfU3U2xglHt6_6KkHiSCNz0IwyhZkmusQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD9LPJgo7pAhXD2qQKHQ9dCXAQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Throughout%20this%20section%20we%20will%20use%20the%20setting%20and%20notation%20of%22&f=false) of Revuz' *Markov chains* book, he's considering a sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $L^1$-functions on a measure space. In Proposition 6.6 (see below), he's talking about limit points of $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in the "$\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$"-topology. What kind of topology is this? I can't find the definition of it inside the book.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma(X,X^*)$ is often used to indicate the weak topology on the Banach space $X$ (and $\sigma(X^*,X)$ indicates the weak-* topology on $X^*$). $L^\infty$ should be identified with $(L^1)^*$ via the Riesz isomorphism $f\mapsto \int (\bullet)\cdot f\,d\mu$.

Comment: So, $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^1$ converges to $f\in L^1$ iff $\int f_ng\to\int fg$ for all $g\in L^\infty$, right?

Comment: Yes. Common notations are $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ and $f_n\stackrel w\to f$. One says that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ *converges weakly* to $f$. @0xbadf00d

Comment: I see. That's the same terminology as for weak convergence in Hilbert spaces. Is there an easy characterization of being a limit point of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ wrt this topology? (I mean, besides the abstract definition of a limit point for a general topological space)

Answer (score 1):

That one is the "Weak Topology", the weakest topology which make every element of $L^{1*}$ continuos. In this case we know $L^{1*}=L^{\infty}$.

Comment: So, what does the author mean when he says that $Tf=f\circ\theta$ for $f\in L^1$ is $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$ continuous? I mean, this map is clearly an isometry on $L^1$.

Comment: I cannot understand where such $T$ is defined. Can you point it out, please?

Comment: $\theta$ is a measurable map on the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$. It is assumed to be measure-preserving, i.e. $\mu\circ\theta^{-1}=\mu$. By this assumption, it's trivial to see that $Tf:=f\circ\theta$ is a linear isometry on $L^p(\mu)$, for all $p\in[1,\infty]$.

Comment: Thank you. The fact is that if a map from $L^1$ is strongly continuos it does not imply that is weakly continuos because the weak topology has less open sets than the other (In this case if it is an isometry on $L^1$ it is not necessarly $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$ continuos.

Comment: So, being $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$-continuous is a stronger condition than being $L^1$-continuous? In any case, is there a nice characterization of $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$-continuity?

Comment: Yes it is. In general you can characterize open neighborhoods of this topology and there are a lot of usefull and very important properties, but about the convergence I think that the most usefull one, in my opinion, is the one given in the previous answer.

Comment: So, $T$ being $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$-continuous means that for all $(f_n)_n\subseteq L^1(m)$ and $f\in L^1(m)$, it holds $\int (Tf_n)g\:{\rm d}m\to\int(Tf)g\:{\rm d}m$ for all $g\in L^\infty(m)$? (Thanks for your effort so far. I've asked a separate question for further questions)

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Thanks. Last question: So, $f\in L^1$ being a limit point of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^1$ in the $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$-topology means $\int f_ng\to\int fg$ for all $g\in L^\infty$, right? But this does not imply that $f$, if it exists, is the only limit point of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^1$. Did I get these things right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes you get it right. I though an usefull characterization (as you ask me) of convergence in weak topology (when the measure space is finite and without atoms). In general $\Gamma \subseteq L^1$ is sequence-compact weakly (you can extract a weakly convergent sequence) if and only if the familiy $\Gamma$ is equi-integrable (for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $u \in \Gamma$  and $\mu(A) < \delta$ we have $\int_A |u| <\epsilon$. It may be usefull for you.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this characterization?

Comment: The theorem is due to Dunford-Pettis, and in the book "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" by Haim Brezis, in the section "Comments on Chapter 4" (Theorem 4.30, page 115) you can find the statement and references where to find the proof.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you wrote that $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$-continuity is a (strictly) stronger notion than $L^1$-continuity, but may it be that this is not true for linear functions as in the present case of the question?

Comment: I mean, $T$ is a linear isometry on $L^1(m)$ and hence, by Hölder's inequality, $$\left|\int T(f_n)g\:{\rm d}m-\int T(f)g\:{\rm d}m\right|\le\left\|T(f_n-f)g\right\|_{L^1(m)}\le\left\|T(f_n-f)\right\|_{L^1(m)}\left\|g\right\|_{L^\infty(m)}=\left\|f_n-f\right\|_{L^1(m)}\left\|g\right\|_{L^\infty(m)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$ for all $g\in L^\infty(m)$ for all $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^1(m)$ and $f\in L^1(m)$ with $\left\|f_n-f\right\|_{L^1(m)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. So, $T$ is continuous (if I'm not missing something) with respect to the weak topology on $L^1(m)$.

Comment: If you have a linear operator from $E$ to $F$ (two Banach spaces) the equivalence condition are:

Comment: I am sorry, I am new, I didn't manage to write.

Comment: If you have a linear operator from $E$ to $F$ (two Banach spaces) the equivalence condition are: continuos from weak to weak, continuos from strong to strong and continuos from strong to weak. But the previous are not equivalent (of course in general, maybe in some case they are) to continuos from weak to strong. In this case if $T$ is an isometry you can switch and conclude the operator is also $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$-continuos so your previous comment is correct. But if $T$ was only linear and continuos the statment you made is not necessarly true.

Comment: I think that it is well shown all you need (In my opinion) in the book I quoted above, in Theorem 3.10, page 61.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I don't see how it could be possible that $T$ is linear and continuous, but not continuous in the weak topology. What I've used in my comment above to conclude the weak continuity would work in exactly the same way when $\left\|T(f_n-f)\right\|_{L^1(m)}\le c\left\|f_n-f\right\|_{L^1(m)}$ for some $c\ge0$. And, as we know, for a linear continuous map between normed spaces, such a $c$ always exists and its minimal choice is precisely the operator norm of $T$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Above you proved that if $f_n$ converges "strongly" to $f$ then $Tf_n$ converges "weakly" to $Tf$. Thus you have used the strong topology at the left and the weak in the right. Because it is an isometry it works also switching the role of $L^1$. You cannot consider the inverse if it was only linear and continuos.

Comment: You're right. That was my mistake. So, you mean that - without the isometry assumption - we cannot make the same conclusion if we only know that $f_n\to f$ weakly, right?

Comment: Yes, if $f_n$ converges weakly we cannot conclude $Tf_n$ converges strongly.

Comment: Unless $\theta$ is invertible (in which case we can write $\int(f_n\circ\theta)g\:{\rm d}m=\int(f_n\circ\theta)(g\circ\theta^{-1}\circ\theta)\:{\rm d}m=\int f_n(g\circ\theta^{-1}$ and clearly $g\circ\theta^{-1}\in L^\infty(m)$) I then don't see how the weak continuity result follows.

Comment: Maybe the weak topology is used in the right part. Actually I don't see how to conclude that your map is weakly continuos.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the right part"? But you see how the conclusion follows in the invertible case, right?

Comment: The right part in your map $T: L^1 \to L^1$. I see the conclusion in the invertible case but not in the general one.

Comment: Hm, yes. That's unfortunate.